# Servlets and Wsdl file

Tags: web-services, wcf, servlets, soap

have a wsdl link and I know the soap request what to send and lso the response format through the membrane soap ui client

I have written a simple html page having 3 fields which i pass through request format of soap and then i get a response based on it. This passing of request and validations are done in servlet which i call through action in form. Now i have a wsdl file link.
How should I use it to make request response from the servlet .please help me with code.

EDIT : THE WSDL CONTAINS WCF BASED SOAP SERVICE .

Answer (score 0):

You have to build a web service client from wsdl using wsimport java utility, then you will get a webservice handle, using that you can build a request, send a request and get a response.

for more details: http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/tutorial/doc/bnayn.html